# django admin "Key 'category' not found in 'SpecificationParameterForm'. Choices are: help_text, name, units, value_type."

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

When I view the change list in the admin interface I can see the `'name', 'category', 'value_type', 'help_text'` fields, proving that the category field is fine. But when I click on a Parameter to get to the change form I get the above error.

Here's my admin:

```
@admin.register(SpecificationParameter)
class SpecificationParameterAdmin(SortableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    For administering Specification Parameters
    """
    # Fields shown in lists
    list_display = ('name', 'category', 'value_type', 'help_text')
    list_per_page = 20
    # related field needs __ due to foreign key
    search_fields = ['name', 'category__name']
    # Change 'Save and add another' to 'Save as new' to easily create similar entries
    save_as = True
    # django 1.10 will default to staying on the page after creating a new one; redirects in 1.9 :(
    # for this purpose, show the id
    readonly_fields = ('id',)
    # Modify the layout of the form, put the optional choices last
    fieldsets = (
        (None,      {'fields': (('name', 'id'), 'category', 'units', 'help_text')}),
        (_('Type'), {'fields': ('value_type',)}),
    )
    inlines = [SpecificationValueChoiceAdminInline]

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        """
        Override to dynamically display choices if multiple choice or checkbox
        """
        instances = []
        for inline in self.inlines:
            if inline == SpecificationValueChoiceAdminInline:
                if obj and obj.value_type in (tup[0] for tup in SpecificationParameter.VALUE_TYPES[1][1]):
                    # for changes and not adds
                    instances += [inline(self.model, self.admin_site)]
            else:
                instances += [inline(self.model, self.admin_site)]
        return instances
```

And a relevant model snippet:

```
class SpecificationParameter(models.Model):
    """
    The fields required by parameters in the specification of a product.
    """
    # _() Provides the name as a translation
    name = models.CharField(_("specification parameter name (public)"), unique=True, max_length=50,
        help_text=_("Be as specific as you can, for example: Minimum DC Voltage"))
    # All parameters in a category need to be removed manually before it will allow you to delete the cetegory
    category = models.ForeignKey(SpecificationCategory, verbose_name=_("parameter category"), on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        help_text=_("Add a new or select an existing parameter section"))
    help_text = models.CharField(_("help text"), max_length=160, help_text=_("Specify any additional information useful to the staff entering values"), blank=True)
    ....
```

[Traceback](http://dpaste.com/3BGRSC7)

Could it be because it's a ForeignKey?
Any ideas much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Removing `fieldsets` removes the error, but the default fields do not include `category`.

I have tried with django 1.10.7 and 1.9.9 with no difference, so removed comment above. Must be a change I made :-/ I have confirmed `category` does not appear in `form.base_fields`

Comment: Please show the full traceback, and the `SpecificationParameter` model.

Comment: Note that changing `self.inlines` is not thread safe. It would be better to override [`get_inline_instances`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_inline_instances`).

Comment: i can see an anomaly and that is help_text, do you have a field with that name? else there is a problem with your model, how come django is treating help_text defined in the name field as another field?

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for the tip, I'll look into get_inline_instances. Added a model snippet. How should I share the traceback?

Comment: On the yellow Django error page (when `DEBUG=True`) there's a *Switch to copy-and-paste view* which makes it easy to grab the traceback and add it to your question.

Comment: I can't spot the problem. You could either try removing code from your model admin until you find out what is causing the problem, or git bisecting the code between Django 1.9 and 1.10 to figure out what change broke your your model admin.

Comment: Check / add readonly_fields = ('field_name', 'other_field') to your ModelAdmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by `SortableAdminMixin` since `category` is in the model Meta `ordering` attribute which is used by this mixin.

I had accidentally overwritten a modified branch when I performed a `pip install -U`.